# Performance of the junction table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, schema

I am at a situation where I want to join two tables that have many to many relation. According to [this URL,](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/table-that-data-RZ006149432.aspx?section=26) [and this one](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9922/~/understanding-and-creating-many-to-many-relationships-in-filemaker-pro) I have to create a separate Join - Table to get a join of my tables. But the problem is there will be many entries in the join table which will make data fetching slow and an overhead of inserting all records manually into the Join - Table.

The two tables are Process and Category such that a process can have many categories and each category can be associated with many processes.

Now there are a total of 90 processes and 200 categories, out of which Process 1 has 117 categories, process 2 has 150 categories, Process 3 has 30 categories and so on.

So if I start making a join table, it will have 117 entries for process 1, then 150 entries for process 2, then 30 categories for process 3 and so on.

How can I join these tables considering the huge numberof entries using Oracle?

Comment: Databases are designed to store data. I don't see billions of records mentioned in your question. Once you are there, you can ask about optimisation and tuning.

Comment: So how do I optimize such data?

Comment: @Bulat is there any alternative available? Something thats faster and doesn't causeso many insert statements?

Comment: Welcome to some of the quirks of relational databases. You are right with what you have concluded with the exception that modern databases are optimized to cope with such link tables.

Comment: @KaiMattern so you mean to say there is no alternative but to switch database? If so, then what database should be taken to consideration

Comment: as soon as you use integers for you foreign and primary keys inserts and selects will come cheap

Comment: @Bulat I'm not yet worried about performance, I'm more worried about insertion of ProcessID and category_ID fields repeatedly in the table with thousands of inserts :(

Comment: again, that is what database is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junction tables are a standard approach for relational databases. You can worry about performance once you hit a problem, otherwise don't spend time on thinking about it.